# On the Partition of Unity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $K$ be a compact set and $\{V_{1},...,V_{n}\}$ an open covering for $K$. We know that there exists a partition of unity subordinate to this covering, that is, $g_{1},...,g_{n}$ are such that $\text{supp}(g_{i})\subseteq V_{i}$, $0\leq g_{i}\leq 1$ is continuous, and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}g_{i}(x)=1$ for all $x\in K$. The author claims that one can assume without loss of generality that $g_{i}(x_{i})=1$ for some $x_{i}\in V_{i}$.

My question is, how this can be done? I try to let $h_{i}=\dfrac{g_{i}}{\|g_{i}\|}$, then surely there is some $x_{i}\in V_{i}$ such that $h_{i}(x_{i})=1$, but then it does not necessarily follow that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}h_{i}(x)=1$ for all $x\in K$.

I wonder if any trick is going on to create such a partition of unity.

Comment: Are you working in $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Comment: No, the author just assumes the underlying space is any topological space.

Comment: Are you allowed to pass to a subcover? If so, by induction you can always pass to a subcover such that no $V_i$ is contained in the union of the $V_j$ for $j\ne i$. Thus, each $V_i$ has some point $x_i$ not contained in any other $V_j$, and therefore, if we have some partition of unity subordinate to this covering, we know that $g_i(x_i)$ must be equal to $1$.

Comment: @JohnGowers, okay, I think you answered my question, thanks a lot.

Comment: Not even [Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space)? ... just any (potentially pathological) topological space?  I'm unsure @JohnGowers idea works in such coarse spaces.  In such spaces, there can be a point that is contained in all nonempty open sets.  For instance, $K$ having a subspace whose inherited subspace topology is a [particular point topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology) seems to be an obstruction.

Comment: @EricTowers Then such a point would not be one of the $x_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you allowed to pass to a subcover? If so, by induction you can always pass to a subcover such that no $V_i$ is contained in the union of the $V_j$ for $j\ne i$. Thus, each $V_i$ has some point $x_i$ not contained in any other $V_j$, and therefore, if we have some partition of unity $(g_i)$ subordinate to this new covering, we know that $g_i(x_i)$ must be equal to $1$ for each $i$.